# iPad App is not launced in landscape mode and getting black screen portion when launching in landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a universal iOS app and currently I am developing it for iPad.
When I am launching the app in the portrait mode app launches fine. But when I launch in landscape mode, portion of the screen becomes back and the app is not launched in landscape mode. I have used

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; }

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;}
```

but the app is not launching in landsape mode and having a black screen portion. I have attached a screen shot as well.[image]. What is the problem here and how to get rid of this?

Comment: do you have a landscape launch image?

Comment: @DanielGalasko Yes I have

Comment: You didn't mention how you implemented landscape and portrait views? Do you have extra (separate) views for 2 modes or do you use size classes? In short, where did you define how your layout should look in landscape mode?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, write this in `ViewDidLoad`, We need to set the insets for `self.view`

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
{
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your view is rotated correctly (the text is upright) you can assume that this problem is not a rotation problem but instead a problem with your layout code/interface builder.

To solve this make sure you pinned your content view to all edges of his superview[image: the screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when iOS8 comes out. With iOS7 all worked fine. After spending a lot of time try to solving i just find that replacing the "launch xib" with a storyboard fix my problem.

So try to add a storyboard, put your actual initial xib into and restart. Don't forget to specify the inizial storyboard into your project's info.

Comment: I am using xib s. not storyboards.

Comment: Me too. I only replaced the launcher xib with storyboard, and it worked. I didn't edit all other xibs.

Comment: Have you tried to change the initial viewcontroller with another just for test?

Comment: Yes of course. I earlier did. but it too did not work

Answer (score 1):

NB you probably have this problem on iPhone6+ as well because it is capable of running springboard in landscape.

I rarely (pretty much never) use storyboards or nibs, so I've had this problem since iOs7 in applications which support rotation. I set up my viewControllers in loadView or viewDidLoad and at that point the viewController does not know the interfaceOrientation.  Because I usually handle rotation programatically as well I just do something like this in viewWillAppearAnimated:

```
{
              BOOL landscape = UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication]statusBarOrientation]);
              BOOL ios8 = NSClassFromString(@"UIPopoverPresentationController")!=NULL;

              if (landscape&&ios8) {

                [self willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication]statusBarOrientation] duration:0.0];

              }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just solved similar problem by setting UIMainStoryboardFile for my app (although this has no side effects on my app as I am setting my ViewControllers in code). So setting main storyboard file has fixed this for iOS 8 through 10.

So set both launch screen and your main interface storyboards.

Setting NSMainNibFile have not fixed that problem for me. Only storyboards.

Main storyboard should contain at least initial view controller that could be empty.

Answer (score -1):

In the appDelegate, set:

```
[self.window setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: It is iOS8, not 7. Maybe you should advice him to use nativebounds.